# JS input validation submit disabled for separate instances

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need each instance of `input` and `submit` to operate independently. What is the best way to handle multiple instances where each `submit` is connected to it's own set of `inputs`?

Since they are unrelated, would `data-attributes` be the best solution?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  validate();
  $('input').on('keyup', validate);
});

function validate() {
  var inputsWithValues = 0;
  var myInputs = $("input:not([type='submit'])");
  myInputs.each(function(e) {
    if ($(this).val()) {
      inputsWithValues += 1;
    }
  });
  if (inputsWithValues == myInputs.length) {
    $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", false);
  } else {
    $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", true);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item1">
  <div><input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" required/></div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit 1" />
</div>
<div class="item2">
  <div><input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" required/></div>
  <div><input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" required/></div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit 2" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Preferred way

I think best solution would be use `form` -tag as it is created for just this use case [HTML Forms](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp).

```
<form id="form-1">
  <input type="text"/>
  <input type="submit>
</form>    
<form id="form-2">
  <input type="text"/>
  <input type="submit>
</form>
```

You can also bind custom Form on submit event handlers and collect form data this way.

```
$('#form-1').on('submit', function(event){ 
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevent sending form as defaulted by browser
  /* Do something with form */ 
});
```

#### Possible but more bolt on method

Alternative methods to this would be to create your own function's for collecting all relevant data from inputs and merge some resonable data object.

I would most likely do this with giving desired class -attribute all inputs I would like to collect at once eg. `<input type="text" class="submit-1" />` and so on. Get all elements with given class, loop through all them and save values into object.

This requires much more work tho and form -tag gives you some nice validation out of the box which you this way have to do yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I think your intuition about using data attributes works great here.

```
var allButtons = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=submit]");

allButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    var inputSet = button.getAttribute("data-input-set");
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text'][data-input-set='" + inputSet + "']");
  });
});
```

In the following code, when an input button is pressed, it will fetch all the inputs with the corresponding "input-set" tag.